# How to set delimiter value in FlatFileReader of spring batch?

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch, batch-processing

I am new on spring batch. My task is to develop code which read a flat file where values are separated by pipe "|". I found that I can do it by FlatFileReader. But I am not getting how to set delimiter value during read and how to map each column with my POJO member variables.

Sample values in flat file are following .

```
3345|742|0|N

3346|743|1|A

3347|742|0|N

3348|742|1|C

3345|743|0|K
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8):

Using Spring Batch

```
DelimitedLineTokenizer tokenizer = new DelimitedLineTokenizer();
tokenizer.setDelimiter("|");
tokenizer.setNames(new String[]{"id", "name"});

DefaultLineMapper lineMapper = new DefaultLineMapper<Seller>();
lineMapper.setLineTokenizer(tokenizer);
```

Answer (score 7):

The `FlatFileItemReader` delegates the parsing of each record to a `LineTokenizer` (via the `LineMapper`).  I'm assuming you're using the `DelimitedLineTokenizer` which allows you to set a delimiter (the default is a ,).  To configure this with a pipe as the delimiter:

```
<bean id="reader" class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileItemReader">
    <property name="resource" value="<SOME_VALUE>"/>
    <property name="lineMapper">
        <bean class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.mapping.DefaultLineMapper">
            <property name="lineTokenizer">
                <bean class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.transform.DelimitedLineTokenizer">
                    <property name="names" value="<LIST_OF_VALUES>"/>
                    <property name="delimiter" value="|"/>
                </bean>
            </property>
            <property name="fieldSetMapper" ref="myFieldSetMapper"/>
        </bean>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Where `<SOME_VALUE>` is the pattern for your file to be read and `<LIST_OF_VALUES>` is the list of column names in your delimited file.